# Range to integral type conversion

Tags: c++, iterator, type-conversion

I am a looking for a template function to convert a range to an integral type. It would look something like this:

```
template<typename InputIterator, typename IntegralType>
IntegralType convert(InputIterator first, InputIterator last)
{
...
}
```

and it could be used like this:

```
vector<char> buf;
int tag=convert<int>(buf.begin(), buf.end());
```

Is there a standard way to do this? Has anyone already done this before?

Thanks

Comment: How do the contents of the range map to the integral output?

Comment: There's a lot of standard ways of converting ranges to numbers, defined in [<algorithm>](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/algorithm) and [<numeric>](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/numeric/)

Comment: What is your mapping from range of values to a single value? sum? mean? median? standard deviation? max? min?

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to parse text messages in tag=value format from a buffer.
We've got stoi(str, pos, base) function in C++11 but in order to call it you need the "str" object to exist and contain the proper value. I need a sort of stoi() but with a range as parameter which could be called like this:

```
string str { "49=SenderCompID|50=SenderSubID|..." };
int tag1 = stoi(str.begin(), str.begin() + str.find('='));
int tag2 = stoi(str.begin()+17, str.begin() + 19);
```

or even better:

```
vector<char> buf { str.begin(), str.end() };
unsigned tag = stointegral<unsigned>(buf.begin(), buf.begin() + 2);
```